# Instafeed JS on prestashop not working properly

Tags: javascript, prestashop, instafeedjs

I have a problem with `instafeed.js` library on prestashop.
I need put my gallery of pictures on my website but I don't find a way to do it.

Is necessary to make files from PS(.tpl)?
Or in back office is it possible to add the code of this library?

Answer (score 0):

Is your question *"How to add a JS plugin to prestashop?"*, have you tried anything?

You can just add the provided code snippets from the instafeed page above the closing `</body>` tag in the `footer.tpl` in your PS theme folder.

Alternatively i found [this module](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/247358-module-instagram-pictures-product-page-tag-feed/) which you could also use to load instagram pictures.

Comment: Thanks very much, tomorrow I'll try put this on my PS. If can't make that work it, I will write about this ! Thanks so much for help guys!